# Change getInternalDate into user readable date?

Tags: php, gmail-api

I got messages by gmail api php,here I have tried to get date by `getInternalDate` is output long number!So I want to change user readable date but I can't when format by `date()` using php!!

```
$single_message = $service->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
$date = $single_message->getInternalDate();//'1464161738000'
var_dump(date("Y",$date));//  1956 ,should be 2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that getInternalDate return a value in miliseconds instead of second.
so you just have to divide it by 1000 and then use the date function.

```
$date = $single_message->getInternalDate() / 1000;
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide $date by 1000 :) the internalDate is in ms.